# Is there a way to check if a port is open on android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, networking, udp

I have already looked at some of the answers on SO but to no avail. How can I check if a port is open already, close it if open already and then open a socket on that port from Java code?

Details: I want to open port number 5000 and bind it to a udp socket. However, every time I open the socket on that port, I get an exception "Address already in use". How can I make sure the port is available first? Overridind onDestroy() to close the socket when terminating the application does not seem to do it.

Comment: Please add more detail, this is not a good question

Comment: What library are you using to create the udp socket? You also have the possibility of that port being used and my firewall settings on total lockdown.

Comment: @Starscream1984 No further detail is required. You may not personally understand the question, but that doesn't by itself make it 'not good'.

Comment: try
{
   Params.datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(Params.udp_port);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   Log.e(TAG, "Socket open failed", e);
}

Answer (score 4):

> I have already looked at some of the answers on SO but to no avail.

Hard to believe.

> How can I check if a port is open already

Try to bind to it as below. If you get a BindException, it's in use.

> close it if open already

You can't.

> and then open a socket on that port from Java code?

```
DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
```

Comment: I use exactly this method as mentioned by you. Please see the code snippet added in comments in my question.

Comment: Never mind. I was creating another socket elsewhere on the same port. I have gone down a different route now and it is all working fine. Thanks for your answers